# Picasa API for Android

Tags: android, picasa, google-data-api

Does somebody know where I can find a good API to send and receive photos from my Android-phone to Picasa? I've been searching for more than 2 days but I can't find a good way.
I think the best way was to do this via `HttpRequests` and using `OAuth2`.
Does somebody have a good example on this?

Comment: check this out https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/ and http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs should be helpful links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have a public facing API described here:

https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java

You are right. You will  have to authenticate your app using OAuth and then send HTTP requests using the provided API's.

It should work on Android. If you need a sample on how to use restful web services on Android, You can see this sample from google:

http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/#git%2FPhotostream%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fandroid%2Fphotostream

It's a sample app that uses the flickr API to stream photos.